# Ajax - Call not being made

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following code:

```
function getChainDeals(chainID) {
    $('#loadingDiv1').show();
    var apiCode = * my unique api code * ;
    var imageURL;
    //Get relevant Image
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://api.8coupons.com/v1/getchainstorelist?key=' + apiCode,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (data) {

            $.each(data, function (key, value) {

                alert('key = ' + key);
                alert('chainid = ' + chainID);

                if (key === chainID - 1) {
                    alert('here');
                    imageURL = value.logoBig;
                    alert('imageURL = ' + imageURL);
                    return false;
                }
            });
            // hide the loading animation
            $('#loadingDiv1').hide();
        },
        statusCode: {
            404: function () {
                alert: ('There was a problem with the server');
            }
        }
    });
    alert(imageURL);
    alert(chainID);
}
```

For some reason however, the `AJAX` call is being skipped and only the final two `alerts` are being processed. I actually used almost identical code earlier in the program which worked fine...

Can anyone see what is going wrong here?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: did you check your page with developer tools/firebug enabled? maybe the ajax call is made, but the response function is wrong ;)

Comment: Check your console, head over to the Network tab, what happens with the request?

Comment: Use Fiddler to see what is happening with the server and what is being sent back

Comment: Thanks dz15. Turns out I was getting a response, but it was just taking a very long time...

Answer (score 1):

You should put the `alert`s inside of the ajax callback because ajax is async:

```
function getChainDeals(chainID) {
    $('#loadingDiv1').show();
    var apiCode = * my unique api code * ;
    var imageURL;
    //Get relevant Image
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://api.8coupons.com/v1/getchainstorelist?key=' + apiCode,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (data) {

            $.each(data, function (key, value) {

                alert('key = ' + key);
                alert('chainid = ' + chainID);

                if (key === chainID - 1) {
                    alert('here');
                    imageURL = value.logoBig;
                    alert('imageURL = ' + imageURL);
                    return false;
                }
            });
            // hide the loading animation
            $('#loadingDiv1').hide();

            alert(imageURL);
            alert(chainID);
        },
        statusCode: {
            404: function () {
                alert: ('There was a problem with the server');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks John. I forgot about AJAX being asynchronous and that things could happen outside of the function before the code inside finished.